# Телеграмм бот не отправляет сообщения

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Недавно начал изучать ботов в телеграмм и возникли кое-какие трудности
Вот мой код:

```
import telebot


myBot = telebot.TeleBot(key)


@myBot.message_handler(commands=["start","stopgame"])
def get_command(mes):
    global d
    if mes.text == "/start":
        myBot.send_message(mes.chat.id, "Стартуем")
        list_1 = [" + ", " - ", " / ", " * "]
        list_2 = [randint(1, 30) for i in range(randint(1, 20))]
        a = (str(choice(list_2))) ; b = choice(list_1) ; c = (str(choice(list_2)))
        d = eval(a + b + c)
        myBot.send_message(mes.chat.id, (a+b+c+" = ?"))
    elif mes.text == "/stopgame":
        myBot.send_message(mes.chat.id, "Stope")


@myBot.message_handler(content_types=("text"))
def mes_handl (mes):
    if mes == int(d):
        myBot.send_message(mes.chat.id,"Верно")



myBot.polling()
```

этот бот должен выводить "Верно " при правильном вводе от пользователя, но такого не происходит.

*Бот генерирует случайный легкий пример и пользователь должен ввести ответ.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на комментарий к [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1218553/234134):

> появился след вопрос, как реализовать нормальный старт т.е когда
> пользователь нажимает старт он запускает игру , она будет подсчитывать
> кол-во правильных и неправильных голосов , и когда пользователь нажмет
> на /stop игра закончится и выведет результаты?

**CREATE TABLE "score" ("id_tlgrm" INTEGER, "answer" TEXT)**

```
import sqlite3

db = 'score.db'


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    list_1 = [' + ', ' - ', ' / ', ' * ']
    list_2 = [randint(1, 30) for i in range(randint(1, 20))]
    a = (str(choice(list_2)))
    b = choice(list_1)
    c = (str(choice(list_2)))
    d = eval(a + b + c)
    print('d', d, type(d))
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(a + b + c + ' = ?'))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2, d)


def start_2(message, d):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        if int(message.text) == int(d):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно')
            save_score(message.chat.id, 'Правильно')
            start(message)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'А вот и нет')
            save_score(message.chat.id, 'Неправильно')
            start(message)
    elif message.text == '/stop':
        all_answer, right, wrong = read_score(message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'Всего ответов - {}\nПравильных - {}\nНеправильных - {}'.format(all_answer, right, wrong))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'а?')


def save_score(id_tlgrm, answer):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    data = [(id_tlgrm, answer)]
    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO score VALUES (?, ?)', data)
    conn.commit()


def read_score(id_tlgrm):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    all_answer = conn.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM score WHERE id_tlgrm = ?', (id_tlgrm,)).fetchone()
    right = conn.execute('SELECT COUNT(answer) FROM score WHERE id_tlgrm = ? AND answer = ?',
                         (id_tlgrm, 'Правильно')).fetchone()
    wrong = conn.execute('SELECT COUNT(answer) FROM score WHERE id_tlgrm = ? AND answer = ?',
                         (id_tlgrm, 'Неправильно')).fetchone()

    if all_answer is None:
        conn.close()
        return None
    else:
        conn.close()
        return all_answer[0], right[0], wrong[0]
```

*не заморачивался с оптимизацией*

[DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/)

Comment: спасибо вы просто лучший <3

Comment: будет здорово, если вы проголосуете "за", это поможет другим пользователям в первую очередь.

Comment: кстати вылазит ошибка:( line 46, in save_score
    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO score VALUES (?, ?)', data)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: score

Comment: а вы создали БД `score.db` с таблицей `score` и столбцами `id_tlgrm`, `answer`?

Comment: а можно ли без базы данных обойтись??

Comment: можете записывать куда вам удобнее, мне проще в БД, для последующего поиска ответов по чат айди.

Comment: у меня просто pycharm не поддерживает, тяжко

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117256/discussion-between-violet-and-belekiy).

Answer (score 2):

ответ пользователя содержится в `mes.text`, а не в `mes`.

и `mes.text` является строкой поэтому приводите ответ пользователя к `int`:

```
@myBot.message_handler(content_types=("text"))
def mes_handl (mes):
    if int(mes.text) == int(d):
```

и нужно исправить подобные вопросы:

- 1 / 1 = ? (1.0 <class 'float'>)
- 5 / 29 = ? (0.1724137931034483 <class 'float'>)

пользователь явно не сможет ответить)

Comment: Спасибо, появился след вопрос ,как реализовать нормальный старт т.е когда пользователь нажимает старт он запускает игру , она будет подсчитовать кол-во правильных и неправильных голосов , и когда пользователь нажмет на /stop игра закончится и выведет результаты??

Comment: добавил ещё один ответ